# 12.04 kernel still on 3.2?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I heard news that the 12.04 kernel will be upgraded to version 3.4, but it's still kernel 3.2 for me and according to ubuntuupdates.org

```
uname -r
3.2.0-38-generic
```

[UbuntuUpdates.org Package search for linux-image](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=linux-image)

Does it only come on newly installed systems or have they just not packaged it yet?

Comment: Where did you read about it?

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant kernel 3.5. 
http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Secure-Boot-comes-to-Ubuntu-12-04-2-LTS-1804203.html
http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/02/14/ubuntu-12-04-2-lts-released/

Comment: @paed808 - you'll need to install the hardware enablement stack as per one of the answers in the dupe link now in your question.